# How to return 1 value on JsonResult

Tags: javascript, html, json, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a problem where I need to use `JsonResult` but will return single value..

May I ask is that possible and how should I use it in my Set of Codes

I want to return the Address but I don't know if it is possible or not. .

```
public JsonResult LoadAddress()
        {

            Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                var address = (from a in db.Clients
                               join b in db.Client_Location
                               on a.ID equals  b.ClientID
                               where a.userId == userId
                                     && a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Worker"))
            {
                var address = (from a in db.Workers
                               join b in db.Worker_Address
                               on a.ID equals  b.WorkerID
                               where a.userId == userId &&
                               a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();

            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Employer"))
            {
                var address = (from a in db.Client_Customer
                               join b in db.Client_Customer_Location
                               on a.ID equals b.Client_CustomerID
                               where a.userId == userId
                                     && a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Err.. If i am not wrong, this is Java, not JavaScript.. They are totally different programming languages.. Please change the tags

Comment: what do you mean by single value? whats your problem? is there an error in this code? if yes whats that?

Comment: @Samleo this is c# asp.net MVC

Comment: @ParvSharma   Cannot Return the Address because it says that cannot resolve symbol

Comment: why not return this in JSON?:
{
    "result": "1"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have a common interface for all the different address types (i.e. `Clients`, `Workers` and `Client_Customer`), you could do:

```
public interface IAddress{
    string Name{get;set;}
    string Street {get; set;}
    // etc
}
```

then, if all relevant address types implement the interface, you'd just do the following:

```
IAddress address = null;
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    address = (IAddress)(from a in db.Clients... etc)
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Worker"))
{
    address = (IAddress)(from a in db.Workers... etc)

}
else if (User.IsInRole("Employer"))
{
    address = (IAddress)(from a in db.Client_Customer... etc)
}
else
{
    address = /// some other default that you want
}
return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**[edit]** - the typical implementation of this would look like, also, you'd need to cast your result as shown in the edit above (i.e. `(IAddress)(etc)`):

```
public class Client : IAddress {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    // etc
    /* now all your other unique properties*/
    public string ClientName{get;set;}    
}

public class Client_Customer : IAddress {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    // etc
    /* now all your other unique properties*/
    public string AnotherName{get;set;}    
}

public class Workers: IAddress {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    // etc
    /* now all your other unique properties*/
    public string WorkerName{get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: tried this but my Query says that `Cannot convert source type Client to Address`

Comment: Ren, you'll need to ensure that you've implemented the interface. let me add further detail to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult LoadAddress()
        {
            Address address = null;
            Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                address = (from a in db.Clients
                               join b in db.Client_Location
                               on a.ID equals  b.ClientID
                               where a.userId == userId
                                     && a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Worker"))
            {
                address = (from a in db.Workers
                               join b in db.Worker_Address
                               on a.ID equals  b.WorkerID
                               where a.userId == userId &&
                               a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();

            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Employer"))
            {
                address = (from a in db.Client_Customer
                               join b in db.Client_Customer_Location
                               on a.ID equals b.Client_CustomerID
                               where a.userId == userId
                                     && a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: tried this but my Query says that `Cannot convert source type Client to Address`

Comment: whats is the type of address that this query returns (from a in db.Clients
                               join b in db.Client_Location
                               on a.ID equals  b.ClientID
                               where a.userId == userId
                                     && a.LogicalDelete == false
                               select a).SingleOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    expando.address = ...
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Worker"))
{
    expando.address = ...

}
else if (User.IsInRole("Employer"))
{
    expando.address = ...
}
return Json(expando.address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```